# Sprache as a round-trip tool

Tags: sprache

Can [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache) be used as a round-trip tool? I understand that with it I can build a parser that can extract information from a given text. But I can reuse the same (simple*) pattern I came up for parsing also to generate text from Information?

Let me give you an example: I implement a parser which is capable of extracting the information `"abc"` from the text `"[abc]"`. Now it would be handy if I could simply provide the value `"abc"` and it would know how to produce the resulting text `"[abc]"`. Thus I would have a round-trip tool to go from text to information and back to text.

*) limited to known number of appearances of symbols (i.e. no `.AtLeastOnce()` etc.)

Comment: There is nothing within Sprache that can do this.  You would have to build a library on top of Sprache to do this.  For simple cases like quotations or surrounding with square brackets it is perfectly possible.